# 301 Redirect : domain.fr --> www.domain.com and www.domain.fr --> www.domain.com

Tags: redirect, apache-2.2, domain, virtualhost

I'm using a Apache2 server with Passenger for my Rails app.

I dunno how to create a 301 redirect in my VirtualHost as :

- domain.fr --> www.domain.com
- www.domain.fr --> www.domain.com

I've tried :

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.domain.com/
```

and

```
Redirect permanent / http://www.domain.com/
```

But it's not the way to do it :-)

Thx for your answers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) to do this. [This article](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html) shows some examples, here's their way to rewrite non-`www.` to `www.`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For your purposes, I'd also extend this with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain\.fr$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.fr$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Of course, the last two could be combined with the proper regex modification in the `RewriteCond`. I'll leave this as an exercise for you, so you have an incentive to learn more about `mod_rewrite`. :-)